# Django: Use LayerMapping to update an existing model?

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django 1.8. I would like to use the [LayerMapping import utility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/) to update an existing model.

This is my models file:

```
class PCT(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True,
                            help_text='Primary care trust code')
    ons_code = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    boundary = models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I already have a row in the model with `code: 03V` and `name: Corby`, and no boundary.

Now I want to import some boundaries for this row from a KML file. This is my import command:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = ''
    help = 'Imports boundaries from KML.'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        filename = 'CCC_Feb2013.KML' 
        ds = DataSource(filename)
        layer_mapping = {
            'code': 'Name',
            'boundary': 'Unknown'
        }
        lm = LayerMapping(PCT, filename, layer_mapping, transform=False)
        lm.save(strict=True, progress=1, verbose=True)
```

The problem I'm having is that this seems to wipe the existing row, and create a new one with no `name` field. Is there any way to update the row using LayerMapping, rather than overwriting it?

Here's a sample of the KML, in case this helps for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Folder>
<description><![CDATA[CCG boundary BSC]]></description>
<Placemark>
<name><![CDATA[03V]]></name>
<description><![CDATA[<br><br><br>
<table border="1" padding="0">
<tr><td>CCGcode</td><td>03V</td></tr>
<tr><td>CCGname</td><td>NHS Corby CCG</td></tr>
    ]]></description>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<open>0</open>
<Style><LineStyle><color>FF000000</color><width>  1</width></LineStyle>   
<PolyStyle><fill>0</fill><outline>1</outline></PolyStyle></Style>
<Polygon>
  <extrude>1</extrude>
  <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode> 
  <tessellate>1</tessellate>
  <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>
    <coordinates>
          -.596387,52.496896,0
          -.609296,52.508583,0...
    </coordinates>
  </LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon> 
  </Placemark>
  ...
  </Folder></kml>
```

If I can't use LayerMapping, please could you explain how to import the boundary from the KML file, without using LayerMapping?

Comment: Does the existing row get recreated without `ons_code` as well as `name` ?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `unique` argument. Looking at the `LayerMapping` source code that should do an update if model already exists, but I haven't tested it, so let me know if it works:

```
lm = LayerMapping(PCT, filename, layer_mapping, transform=False, unique='code')
```

**EDIT**

But for it to actually update the field it necessary to override `LayerMapping.save` method. Unfortunately it is not possible to make it very DRY. Extend  `LayerMapping` and copy all the code from original save and replace lines [561](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py#L561) - [565](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py#L565) like so:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils.layermapping import LayerMapping

class UpdateLayerMapping(LayerMapping):

    def save(self, verbose=False, fid_range=False, step=False,
         progress=False, silent=False, stream=sys.stdout, strict=False):

        ...

                        #geom = getattr(m, self.geom_field).ogr
                        #new = OGRGeometry(kwargs[self.geom_field])
                        #for g in new:
                        #    geom.add(g)
                        #setattr(m, self.geom_field, geom.wkt)
                        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
                            setattr(m, key, value)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and apologies for the delay replying. Unfortunately this now generates the following error: `File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py", line 564, in _save geom.add(g) AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: @Richard, I can see what the problem is, when updating it tries to add new geometry to a collection of geometries, that it assumes is already attached to the field. It seems to me like  bug, or poorly designed feature. So the only way to achieve what you are trying to do is to customize `LayerMapping.save` method. I'll add it to the answer.